# Dalli Client - how to connect with unix socket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Dalli Client is a little faster gem than standard memcached library.

Client may be initialized by: `dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211')`

But now I'm in need to create client using unix socket, for example file "tmp/memcached.sock" (this is good speed up). After reading documentation, code and examples I don't know how to create client based on socket. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made a commit to make dalli working with unix sockets. Now it will be possible to do it:

```
Dalli::Client.new("/tmp/memcached.sock")
```

**Edit:**
to people searching for answers why unix socket does not work - it has been removed in 2.x (if you want to use UNIXSocket, please use latest 1.x, refer to https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/273)

Answer (score 0):

You can start memcached with a socket by using a command like `memcached -d -u someuser -s /tmp/memcached.sock -a 00755` This command would run Memcached as a dameon, with the user set to someuser and the socket location would be /tmp/memcached.sock with permissions of 775.

Your installation might already create this socket by default so try replacing the URI with the location of the socket above and it might just work using something like this:

```
dc = Dalli::Client.new('/tmp/memcached.sock')
```

If this doesn't work for you the socket might need to be created or it might be in a different location.

Comment: irb(main):005:0> Dalli::Client.new("/tmp/memcached.sock").set("A","B")
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0):

At this time, only versions 1 of Dalli  supports sockets. Modify your Gemfile to reference the v1 branch or change your Dalli config to reference Memcached using port.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'dalli', '~>1.1' # for socket support
```

Socket support was dropped in Dalli v2.

Cite: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/273